# accessing GuestAuthentication object for getting list of processes in guest for Vmware Java API

Tags: java

I am using VMwareExsi APIs that is vijava sdk for accessing some of the VMs which are running in the hypervisor.
I am trying to get list of all processes running in one of the Vms.
I have GuestProcessManager instance with me, and I am calling
 GuestProcessManager .listProcessesInGuest(GuestAuthentication gauth,pids).
As evident ,gauth is mandatory parameter for the method.But I am unable to get GuestAuthentication object . How can I retrieve it?

I tried following approach:

```
Folder rootFolder = si.getRootFolder();

ManagedEntity[] mes = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder)

  .searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");

NamePasswordAuthentication auth = null;

  auth = new NamePasswordAuthentication();

  String username = "xxx";

  String password = "xxxxxxx";

  long[] pids=null;

         auth.setUsername(username);

         auth.setPassword(password);

         auth.setInteractiveSession(true);

  GuestProcessInfo[] processInfo=si.getGuestOperationsManager().getProcessManager((VirtualMachine)mes[1]).listProcessesInGuest(auth,pids);
```

What am I getting is :Exception caused:::VI SDK invoke exception:com.vmware.vim25.GuestOperationsUnavailable.

If I set interactivesession to false , exception message changes to Exception caused:::VI SDK invoke exception:com.vmware.vim25.GuestComponentsOutOfDate . I am using vijava5.5 .jar for development .

System on host & EXSI version : vmnix-x86VMware ESXi 5.5.0 .

I am attaching below the some of the informations I am fetching from my VM, this information shows VM is in running state .
CPU Allocation Shares ::2000

Memory Allocation Shares ::20480
RunTime Max CPU Usage::5799

RunTime Max Memory Usage::2048

Runtime memory overhead::36024320

Average CPU utilization   1.375237150741635E-4

Listing process for VmVirtualMachine:2 @ 10.126.77.45

Exception caused:::VI SDK invoke exception:com.vmware.vim25.GuestOperationsUnavailable

Guest OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (64-bit)

VM Version:vmx-10

CPU:4 vCPU

Memory:12288 MB

Memory Overhead:373.0514 MB

VMware Tools:guestToolsRunning

IP Addresses:10.126.77.221

State:running

Comment: Vmwaretools is running ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to fetch other values like cpu utilization or memory usage .

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some more details 
Vcenter version, Esxi Version, VMware tools version etc.

What I suspect is either vmware tools is not running properly or some version mismatch is blocking the authentication.

I have left java years back. But when I wrote the given below code, it is working fine with me. Can you check this code in your setup !

```
        ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL("https://10.22.10.13/sdk"), "Administrator", "Password", true);
        Folder rootFolder = si.getRootFolder();
        String name = rootFolder.getName();
        ManagedEntity[] mes = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");
        if(mes==null || mes.length ==0)
        {
          return;
        }

        VirtualMachine vm = null;
        for (ManagedEntity entity : mes) {
            if (entity.getName().equals("Ubuntu12")){
                vm = (VirtualMachine)entity;
                break;
            }
        }
        NamePasswordAuthentication creds = new NamePasswordAuthentication();
        creds.username = "reuben";
        creds.password = "reuben";

        GuestProcessInfo[] processes = si.getGuestOperationsManager().getProcessManager(vm).listProcessesInGuest(creds, null);
        for (GuestProcessInfo process: processes){
            System.out.println("Process Name: "+process.name);
        }
```

Comment: Sir, I think your and mine codes are exactly similar.I have appended my code in the question. When you say version mismatch, then what do you mean by that ?